# How Data Transfer To Other Class Component

Tags: reactjs, variables, components, data-transfer, react-component

I need send a variable on Customer and how can i catch this variable in other component?

```
    class CustomerForm extends Component {

 handleClick=(e)=>{
        const container = document.getElementById("customerform");
        var xml=(
          "xml control"
        );
var transformValue = window.getComputedStyle(container).getPropertyValue("transform");

      };


render(){
<div  onClick={this.handleClick} id="customerform" className="box" > 
               

            </div>

}
}export default CustomerForm;
```

I need transform and xml variable in other component.

```
  class MainComponent extends Component {
    render() {
    <CustomerForm /> 
like var xml=...??
    }
    
    }export default MainComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `props` to pass data between components. you can take a look at **reacts docs** this might help! https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: But i dont have parent component so my variable not goes Main to Customer. My variable is goes Customer to Main. I cant use <Main variable={variable}/> because i need show it  Main, main have many div, button style